# Homomorphisms induced by $h$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be spaces.  Let $x_0 \in X$ and let there be a continuous function $h$ such that $h(x_0)=y_0$.  Then there is a homomorphism $h_{*}: \pi_1(X,x_0)\to \pi_1(Y,y_0)$ by the rule $h_{*}\circ [a]=[h\circ a].$

I'm not sure how to show this is a well defined homomorphism.

I was told to take two classes of paths $[a]$ and $[b]$ in $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ and suppose $H$ is a homotopy between $a$ and $b$.  Then $f\circ H$ is a homotopy between $f \circ a$ and $f\circ b$. I don't understand why this shows it is well defined.

Comment: Because well-definedness means that the result is independent of the choice of equivalence class. The equivalence classes in $\pi_1 (X,x_o)$ are homotopic curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show $h_*$ is well-defined say we have $[a]=[b] \in \pi_1(X,x_0)$. We need to show $h_*([a])=h_*([b])$ that is show that $[h\circ a]=[h\circ b]$. As $[a]=[b]$ there exists a path homotopy $H:I\times I \rightarrow X$ from $a$ to $b$. Define $F:I \times I \rightarrow Y$ by $F(s,t)=h(H(s,t))$ and $F$ will be a path homotopy from $h\circ a$ to $h\circ b$ which implies that $[h\circ a]=[h\circ b]$ as needed. Let me know if you want me to explain more.

Comment: It kind of confuses me why there are more than one equivalence class.  If I'm not mistaken, $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ has all the curves such as $\alpha(0)=x_0=\alpha(1)$.  It seems like that means there is only one class.

Comment: It depends on the space. If we let $X=\mathbb{R}$ then as the space is path connected, we can choose any base point so say we pick $x_0=0$. In this case, $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ does have only one element as every loop based at $x_0=0$ is path-homotopic to the constant loop. This is pretty quick to show. So in that space there is only one equivalence class but many representatives for that one class. An example of a space where there is more than one distinct class is say we let $Y=\mathbb{R^2}-\{(0,0)\}$. Say we take $y_0=(1,1)$. $\pi_1(Y,y_0)$ will have more than one distinct class.

Comment: For more than one distinct class take a loop in $Y=\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ that is some circle that passes through $(1,1)$ and "inside" the circle is $(0,0)$. Denote that class by $[a]$ and then take the constant loop at $(1,1)$ and call its class $[i]$. $[a]\neq [i]$ as we can't continuously deform the circle loop to the constant loop so there is more than one class here.

Answer (score 1):

the map $h_{*}$ is well-defined, for if $F$ is a path homotopy between the paths $a$ and $a'$, then $h\circ F$ is a path homotopy between the paths $h\circ a$ and $h\circ a'$.